# Move to another Viewcontroller via RightBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem

I have the following situation:

I have created a rightBarButtonItem in my `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "New", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "newProject")
```

My question is, how can I move through tapping this button programmatically to another Viewcontroller, using the segue "show (e.g push)".

I have the beginning like this:

```
func newProject() {

}
```

But I don't know further, because I'm a beginner in Swift.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**Update:**

So, this is the whole area, where the error appears:

```
class NewProject: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, CustomPickerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtProjectName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvDescription: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtStartDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEndDate: UITextField!

    var hud: MBProgressHUD?
    var customPicker: CustomPickerView?
    var dictProject: NSDictionary!
    var projectID: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = "Create new Project"
        self.hud = MBProgressHUD(view: self.view)
        self.view.addSubview(self.hud!)
        self.projectID = ("\(self.dictProject!["id"]!)")
        self.populateFields()
    }
    func populateFields() {
        if nil != self.dictProject!["name"] {
            self.txtProjectName.text = self.dictProject!["name"] as? String
        }

    }
```

And the error appears on this line here:

```
self.projectID = ("\(self.dictProject!["id"]!)")
```

And this line here:

```
    if nil != self.dictProject!["name"] {
```

Comment: Did you segue to Viewcontroller via story board from right bar button ?

Comment: No, I don't want this. Is it possible to make this programmatically?

Comment: have you created viewcontroller from storyboard ?

Comment: Yes. But because the navigationbar exists automatically due to the show (e.g push) segue, I can't edit the navigationbar and make the button by GUI. That's why I have created it programmatically.

Comment: @Walker Actually, the navigation bar should still be there. Could you send a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Does your dictProject dictionary contain any data?

Comment: Where do you set the value of `dictProject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your segue an identifier in the storyboard (i.e. `"NewProject"`) and then perform it like this:

```
func newProject() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("NewProject", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: It gives me a crash and the error looks like this:"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Could you check out where in your code this error is caused?

Comment: That's not really helpful... Can't you see at which line of code your app crashes?

Comment: No, I can't. It opens the assembler code and shows me the breakpoints with the error above.

Comment: Can you see anything useful in the debug navigator in the left panel once your app crashes? Below Thread 1 you should be able to see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the left panel. You should see Thread 1 with its current stack right below (with `start` at the bottom, and `main` right above). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Try setting up an exception breakpoint (Google it if you don't know what it is). That should make it more clear.

Comment: Either `dictProject` is `nil`, or it has no `"id"` key.

Comment: But I have 2 other viewcontroller-files where the dictProject is defined the same way. Why would it crash the third time? I have a tableview, in the class of it, I define dictProject the same way as I have mentioned above. And when you tap its cells it navigates to another viewcontroller, where I redefine the SAME WAY dictProject (the second time).  And with the rightBarButtonItem I try the same, and it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know, but you can easily set a breakpoint right before it crashes to check whether `dictProject` is `nil` or not.

Comment: Either way, that doesn't really have anything to do with this question anymore.

Comment: It worked now, due to the breakpoint, I had an idea. Thank you very much for your help, really appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)